# how to set background image for only title content of an childwindow in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

how to set background image for only title  content of an childwindow  in silverlight?
and i dont need background image for the whole child window!
can any one help me?

Comment: One way you can achieve this is by re-styling the childwindow.:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Malcolm said in comments, you want to re-template the whole ChildWindow.

[Default ChildWindow Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833070(VS.95).aspx)

Take the styles as posted here and modify them to suit your needs.  You will probably need to modify this section:

```
<Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" IsTabStop="False" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="6,0,6,0" />
    <Button x:Name="CloseButton" Grid.Column="1" IsTabStop="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="15" Height="14" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" />
</Grid>
```

Your image will need to be the background for the `Grid`